# Is disabling Eigen vectorization affecting Vector3/Matrix3 computations as well?

Tags: c++, eigen, memory-alignment

I have been bitten by the infamous problem described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html) (well, my problem was crashing for no apparent reason rather than throwing an assertion).

The problem has been fixed by defining `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` and `EIGEN_DISABLE_UNALIGNED_ARRAY_ASSERT` as described in the last section of the linked given above:

```
Three possibilities:

    * Use the DontAlign option to Matrix, Array, Quaternion, etc. objects that gives you trouble. This way Eigen won't try to align them, and thus won"t assume any special alignment. On the down side, you will pay the cost of unaligned loads/stores for them, but on modern CPUs, the overhead is either null or marginal. See here for an example.

    * Define EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY . That disables all 16-byte (and above) static alignment code, while keeping 16-byte (or above) heap alignment. This has the effect of vectorizing fixed-size objects (like Matrix4d) through unaligned stores (as controlled by EIGEN_UNALIGNED_VECTORIZE ), while keeping unchanged the vectorization of dynamic-size objects (like MatrixXd). But do note that this breaks ABI compatibility with the default behavior of static alignment.

    * Or define both EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE and EIGEN_DISABLE_UNALIGNED_ARRAY_ASSERT. This keeps the 16-byte alignment code and thus preserves ABI compatibility, but completely disables vectorization.

If you want to know why defining EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE does not by itself disable 16-byte alignment and the assertion, here's the explanation:

It doesn't disable the assertion, because otherwise code that runs fine without vectorization would suddenly crash when enabling vectorization. It doesn't disable 16-byte alignment, because that would mean that vectorized and non-vectorized code are not mutually ABI-compatible. This ABI compatibility is very important, even for people who develop only an in-house application, as for instance one may want to have in the same application a vectorized path and a non-vectorized path.
```

While I understand the implications for the relevant structures (i.e. the ones listed [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicFixedSizeVectorizable.html)), I am unsure whether or not other data structures, without this alignment problem (such as Vector3/Matrix3) are also affected. Now I could probably benchmark it myself, but I am not interested in having results for just one platform and one or two compilers - I would like to understand the underlying mechanisms. My program mostly deals with those unaffected data structures, with only a few Matrix2/Quaternion here and there, hence why paying a huge cost for this might not be the preferable option in my case.

Thanks!

**EDIT (in response to @chtz's comment)**

1. If I try to build my program without `-DNDEBUG` (by changing from `RelWithDebInfo` to `Debug` in my ccmake conf), my program segfaults in a very nice way:

```
215 template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Packet4d pload<Packet4d>(const double*  from) { EIGEN_DEBUG_ALIGNED_LOAD return _mm256_load_pd(from); }
```

Good to know for next time, as I could have pinpointed the problem *much* faster..!

2. I also tried to compile with c++17, however the problem persists. I have a dependency (ceres) that was compiled without c++17. I don't know if that may be the reason enabling c++17 doesn't fix my problem, but in any case, I fear this may cause other issues when interacting with ceres (especially since I'm using quaternions with ceres)

Comment: Objects which don't have a natural size which is a multiple of 16 bytes are never aligned in Eigen, so this won't have any effect on them. I suggest just using `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY` if you have trouble with aligning some data structures (and don't want to deal with them individually). Compiling with C++17 may also resolve most of your issues. And generally, if you crash for non-apparent reasons, compile without `-DNDEBUG` first, to see if it helps you pin down the issue.

Comment: @chtz thank you for your input, I edited my question and replied to the points you made :) I guess I will stick to just `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY` and see how it goes

Comment: Linking together parts compiled with and without c++17 probably will cause many other issues. Not sure what kind of answer you are expecting here. Try to provide a [mre] and add the `ceres-solver` tag, if the problem is related to that.